# page refreshes after ajax call, when using "move_uploaded_file"-method in php script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to upload files by dropping them in a `div`-element. My ajax-call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "upload.php",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function(response){
        alert(response);
    });
```

my upload.php looks like this:

```
$filename = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$target_path = $directory . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$target_file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
//[some sql here]
move_uploaded_file($target_file, $target_path);
echo $target_path;
```

Dropping a file into the `div`-element uploads it to the server and enters the data into my database, but it also refreshes the index.php page. When I delete the `move_uploaded_file($target_file, $target_path);`-line, the page no longer refreshes. Desired outcome is for the file to be uploaded to the server, the data to be entered into the database and index.php not be refreshed.

Also dumping my entire upload.js file, in case I missed something obvious:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropArea").on("dragover", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
    $("#dropArea").on("dragenter", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
    $("#dropArea").on("drop", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        let dataTransfer = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer
        let files = dataTransfer.files;
        let formData = new FormData();
        ([...files]).forEach(function(element){
            formData.append("file[]", element);
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pages/uploadScript.php",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        }).done(function(response){
            alert(response);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't see any reason why the PHP code would affect whether the page refreshes. Since you're using AJAX, refreshing is controlled entirely by the JavaScript code.

Comment: Drag and drop should never cause a refresh by itself.

Comment: I don't understand why the page refreshes when "move_uploaded_file" is present and when its not, it doesn't. I left everything else unchanged and only removed this one line and the page no longer refreshes. I agree that it must have to do with the javascript code, as the page refreshes AFTER the `done`-method is called and not during php script execution.

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Do you have any error handling in the JS code that you haven't shown us?

Comment: The done-method is called right before the page refreshes and if I add code after the ajax method, it executes as well. There are no errors in the console that I can see.

Comment: I still say there's nothing in the code you've posted that can possibly cause a page refresh, it must be from something else.